# Not able to click on link which is like nested tag <div><tag>"content"</tag></div>

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

html code:

```
<div id="content1" class="hide"><strong>Own Account</strong><br/>Transfer funds to your own accounts in the same branch or other branches.</div>
<div id="content2" class="hide"><strong>Accounts of Others</strong><br>Transfer funds to Intra-Bank beneficiary accounts in the same bank (same branch or other branches).</div>
<div id="content3" class="hide"><strong>Inter-Bank Beneficiary</strong><br>Transfer funds to beneficiary accounts in other banks including State Bank Group Associate Banks.</div>
<div id="content4" class="hide"><strong>Issue Demand Draft</strong><br>Send request for issue a draft online using funds in a transaction accounts, and select the branch at which the draft is payable.</div>

<div id="content8" class="hide"><strong>Donations</strong><br>Donate online to religious and charitable institutions.</div>


<!-- <div id="content7" class="hide"><strong>Credit Card (VISA) Bill Pay</strong><br>Transfer funds to any Credit Card (VISA) Bill using funds in your transaction accounts.</div> -->
<div id="content7" class="hide"><strong>Credit Card (VISA) Beneficiary</strong><br>Transfer funds to any Credit Card (VISA)using funds in your transaction accounts.</div>
<div id="content9" class="hide"><strong>NRI eZ Trade Funds Transfer</strong><br>If you are an NRI, you can transfer funds from parent account to the NRE PIS account to trade in stock. </div>
```

I want to fetch "Own Account" from this tag and click onto that.

I tried :

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("content2").click()
```

but this won't work and error was

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Stacktrace:

I guess it's trying to access own account inside `<strong></strong>` tag and hence not able to find,

but how to get that is bugging me.

my code as a a whole is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.onlinesbi.com")
assert "State Bank of India" in driver.title
login_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('LOGIN')
login_link.click()


login_link2 = driver.find_element_by_link_text('CONTINUE TO LOGIN')
login_link2.click()


usrname = driver.find_element_by_name("userName")
usrname.send_keys("*********")

passwrd = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
passwrd.send_keys("*******")


login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Login'][@type='submit']")
login_button.click()


login_button2 = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Payments/Tra`enter code here`nsfers')
login_button2.click()
```

Comment: Update Post with Pertaining Title

Comment: @ N.V Prasad any help now? this is bugging me a lot. not able to proceed , for now able to get someting without error messages. but no further progress

Answer (score 0):

The exception you get means the element you want to click is not visible when you are trying to click it. You can use explicit wait to make sure the element is visible before the click

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elem = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#content2 > strong")));
elem.click()
```

This will wait up to 10 seconds for the element to be visible before clicking on it.

Another option is using JavaScript to click

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('content2').click()")
```

Or

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("content2")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
```

Or

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#content2 > strong")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
```

Comment: the command wont work 
"wait =WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elem = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_id("content2")));
elem.click()"

i am using pycharm, and this function WebDriverWait is not displaying automatically
any package to be added for this?

Comment: @vinay `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
line 274, in _find_element
    return driver.find_element(*by)
TypeError: find_element() argument after * must be a sequence, not WebElement

Comment: error C:\Users\vmurshilly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe C:/Users/vmurshilly/PycharmProjects/sandlogin/sandlogin.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vmurshilly/PycharmProjects/sandlogin/sandlogin.py", line 34, in <module>
    elem = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "content2")));
 "C:\Users\vmurshilly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: the elem.click is not working, after wait.until line(2nd line in ur code) someting missing :(

Comment: we can see that the content2 is in tag <strong>content2</strong> so this is where i am stuck with how to access that from inside <strong> tag?

Comment: @vinay Is there `frame` or `iframe` tag in the html?

Comment: By the way, the `<strong>` tag is inside the `content2` element.

Comment: @vinay It doesn't necessarily means anything. but I guess  `class="hide"` means the element is not visible. Try to click the child element `wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#content2 > strong")));`

Comment: yes its visible : <div id="content2" class="hide"><strong>Accounts of Others</strong><br>Transfer funds to Intra-Bank beneficiary accounts in the same bank (same branch or other branches).</div> , but content2 class is hidden probably thats y we are not able to click. its bank webpage, probably they have hidden it for security

Comment: sorry, didnt update regarding that, no it didnt work :(   elem1 = wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#content2 > strong")); i tried this. but still not able to get click.

Comment: @vinay I added option using javascript, it doesn't care the element is hidden.

Comment: driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('content2').click()") the code donot throw error, but there is no click on the link "Account of Others" it shoud click on that link "Account of Others" and then further we can proceed .

Comment: @vinay I added two more options

Comment: not working for both, no error but click is not working. i even tried this:  elem = driver.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#content2 > strong"); print(elem.get_attribute('innerHTML') " this prints me "Accounts of others, so saved this in another object and tried .click() but failed again :( really confusing.   http://yizeng.me/2014/04/08/get-text-from-hidden-elements-using-selenium-webdriver/ using this link i tried to execute java script as arguments[0] but again failed.